# Can I preselect data-filtervalue with url?

Tags: html, url, triggers

Is there an option to have url which will preselect one item from dropdown which is with the following syntax:

```
<li role="presentation">
<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-filtervalue="value">Select Value</a>
</li>
```

Can I preselect the "**value**" ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think what you want to do can only be done with Javascript or with a back-end language.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data value with jQuery

```
var optionVal = $('ul#my-id').attr('data-filtervalue');
```

then remove the trigger for the link with

```
event.preventDefault()
```

```js
$('ul li a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var linkVal = $(this).attr('data-filtervalue');
  
  console.log(linkVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li role="presentation">
<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-filtervalue="value">Select Value</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I wonder if there is a way to do this with some kind of url trigger, so I can put URL address in the browser and see only the " value " items